# CSS HELP, Underline and Overline

Tags: html, css

Hey guys this is the html code and I am stuck as to how to underline the word Bonjour and overline  Auhjord'hui. Please help.

```
<div>
     <p><span>Bonjour</span> le monde <span>aujourd'hui</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Underlining can be done by:

```
p span:first-child
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Overlining can be done similarly:

```
p span:last-child
{
     text-decoration: overline;
}
```

Be aware that, while these selectors will work with the limited code that you provided, they will style **all** spans that are children of paragraphs. You should be very careful about that.

These selectors are not ideal, but **they will work** given the situation.

---

### More info on Selectors:

> Typically, it is better practice to use classes or ids to style elements, however, per your situation, given that you are not allowed to edit the HTML at all, you may ignore this altogether. I am simply leaving this here for reference.

You may consider adding classes or ids to the spans, as the selectors I gave you are probably not what you are looking for; they only applied because they will work with what you gave me.

You'd be better off doing something like:

```
<div>
    <p><span class="under">Bonjour</span> le monde <span class="over">aujourd'hui</span></p>
</div>
```

Then you would target them with:

```
.under
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.over
{
    text-decoration: overline;
}
```

Comment: yes i know that i could add the class, HOWEVER the teacher asked me NOT to change anything in the body.. is this a mistake on his part?

Comment: i know exactly what to do if i was able to create a span class.. however im stuck since its not there

Comment: Well it's not a mistake *per se*, I'm just saying that in practice, you would add a class to target the spans *properly* (using that word loosely). In this case, you can go with my original solution. Those selectors will target the proper spans, or you could use the same rules with inline-CSS. However, neither of those solutions are really good practice. Most people will tell you that inline-CSS is the root of all evil, but it does have its own uses. If your instructor told you not to change the HTML, then use one of these two solutions.

Comment: @MIrzaCelik If you are not allowed to edit the HTML **AT ALL**, then your best solution would be to go with the start of my answer: targeting with :first-child and :last-child. Those will work, however, they are going to style **all of the spans** that are children of p elements. I don't know of another way to explicitly target those two elements differently without directly editing the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy solution would be to add the style to the span:

```
<span style="text-decoration:underline">Bonjour</span>
```

and

```
<span style="text-decoration:overline">aujourd'hui</span>
```

Ok as a one off, but if you need to re-use them, I would create a class for each to keep the style separate (as per the previous answer)

Comment: i appreciate all the help, but i am still confused as to how i would make BONJOUR underline in CSS code, without changing anything to the html code.

Comment: You still need a way to tell the two spans apart. The only way to do this with just css is to use child selectors, as per the other answer.